# Room. DaoImpl builds incorrect

Tags: android, kotlin, entity, android-room, dao

There is entity `Style` and dao `StyleDao`

```
@Dao
interface StyleDao : BaseDao<Style> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Style")
    suspend fun get(): List<Style>
}
```

and

```
@Entity
data class Style(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0,
    var name: String = "Новый стиль",
    @Embedded(prefix = "rtk_") var rtk: Rtk = Rtk(),
    @Embedded(prefix = "st_") var static: Static = Static(),
    @Embedded(prefix = "ppk_") var ppk: Ppk = Ppk()
) : Selectable(), Serializable {

    companion object {
        const val STYLE = "style"
    }
}
```

`Style` includes 3 objects Rtk, Static, Ppk:

```
data class Rtk(...) : StylePart(), Serializable
data class Static(...) : StylePart(), Serializable
data class Ppk(...) : StylePart(), Serializable
```

More then that Ppk is almost copy of Static. But after build Static isn't included into `StyleDaoImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

ooh, it very simple stupid mistake
"static" is keyword(not in Kotlin, but StyleDao_Impl is java file)
So, solution of this problem is just rename variable and class